# Варианты переадресации на mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

`/page` в `/page.php`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/{0,1}$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Какие еще могут быть варианты такой переадресации посредством mod_rewrite ?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает этот вариант?

Comment: @Visman из-за него не срабатывает `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");`, точнее срабатывает, но не происходит переадресации: пользователь остается но той странице, где был вызван этот заголовок.

Comment: Так может файла такого нет? Замените `[QSA,L]` на `[QSA,L,R]` и посмотрите какую страницу попытается открыть.

Comment: @Visman так выдает `Error 403` и в адресной строке открывается полный путь к файлу с которого посылался заголовок 404. (это на localhost)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^page(/?)+$ /page.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: page - может отличаться и вмещать другие символы a-z